# Problem when protecting API with identity server - not working after login in Angular

Tags: c#, angular

I am trying to protect an API in .net Core 2.0 with identity server, the UI was done with Angular, I think I already have done most of the job but after login in angular i can see this error in the console:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'https://localhost:44375/connect/authorize?client_id=js&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A58906%2Fsignin-oidc&response_type=id_token%20token&scope=openid%20profile%20roles%20api1%20offline_access&response_mode=form_post&nonce=636939599510409570.MGYzMTFjMzItZmUyMC00ODU3LTg4ZjctM2U4MmI0NzAzMGZlNGE3YTNmODEtNzkyNi00MDViLTgxY2MtYWQ0ZjYxZmU0NWJm&state=CfDJ8O2EEtV_W31JlCz9gl525Qd1Jg8V7r2jAMhzD_Q_VVDwSnlzrivuvFibSJD1WOjL_gueXbDQIQd8A3zpDTGQ5cQofWOyiWfCuEMJG361u6mJM1PCGKF0W0O40sfhv698VRw6m1z0lJklAaAx27g4MbdSLiq3WcCcpfX-Q30Hy3DFRyRuT-calMfySkYfyejpptDyBGb2uv-rP4D9vEHBRvyRS3Cq60VqSTn7-r_bpA52xM7vG0UFbEqQ4EMqAW2S2-6I1ccqKDJat8eKBo9p8jmp6YoOjCv3wcGKY1RPJz7b-Auu7xIPQwm2FeJ2j-LQF_v6ao2VY7fm4SW7CnNAinNJwaRtDOOxbNqPhjVOvayPJc2BR79Uitf2KaSUFg11Xv-llTuEv9aInJJRL2V1ZYH72iTp8jhndThWNFNtDpBU&x-client-SKU=ID_NETSTANDARD1_4&x-client-ver=5.2.0.0'
>   (redirected from
>   'http://localhost:58906/api/ClienteES/ConsultarClientes?CantidadRegistros=30&PaginaActual=1')
>   from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

I already registered the clients in the identity server project, and I also did the setup in angular an in the API.

this is the code in the Startup.cs in the API

```
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = "cookie";
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
        })
        .AddCookie("cookie")
        .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
        {
            options.Authority = "https://localhost:44375/";
            options.ClientId = "ApiPrincipal";
            options.ClientSecret = "mysecret";
            options.SignInScheme = "cookie";
            options.SaveTokens = true;
            options.ResponseType = "code id_token";
            options.Scope.Add("openid");
            options.Scope.Add("profile");//
            options.Scope.Add("offline_access");

        });
```

--this is the configuration in angular--

```
authority: 'https://localhost:44375/',
client_id: 'js',
redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:4200/auth-callback',
post_logout_redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:4200/',
response_type: "id_token token",
scope: "openid profile api1 roles offline_access",
filterProtocolClaims: true,
loadUserInfo: true
```

an these are the clients in the identity server project(.net core)
new Client

--client fot angular --

```
        {
            ClientId = "js",
            ClientName = "JavaScript Client",
            AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
            AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
            AccessTokenLifetime = 151200,
            RequireConsent = false,
            RedirectUris = redirects.RedirectUris,
            PostLogoutRedirectUris = redirects.PostLogoutRedirectUris,
            AllowedCorsOrigins = redirects.AllowedCorsOrigins,
            AllowedScopes =
                {
                    StandardScopes.OpenId.Name,
                    StandardScopes.Profile.Name,
                   // StandardScopes.Roles.Name,
                   "roles",
                    StandardScopes.OfflineAccess.Name,
                    "api1"
                }
        }
```

--client for API--

```
            {
                ClientId = "ApiPrincipal",
                ClientName = "Cliente utilizado por el api principal de Mawa",
                RequireConsent = false,
                ClientSecrets = new List<Secret> { new Secret("mysecret".Sha256()) },
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials,
                //AllowRememberConsent = true,
                AlwaysSendClientClaims=true,
                AllowedScopes = new List<string>
                {
                    StandardScopes.OpenId.Name,
                    StandardScopes.Profile.Name,
                    StandardScopes.OfflineAccess.Name//,
                    //"ApiAuditor"
                },
                //RedirectUris = new List<string> { "http://localhost:1424/signin-oidc" },//MTA
                //PostLogoutRedirectUris = new List<string> { "http://localhost:1424/" }//MTA
                RedirectUris = new List<string> { "http://localhost:58906/signin-oidc" },//Pemarsa
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = new List<string> { "http://localhost:58906/" }//Pemarsa
             }
```

I want to login in angular and I want the API to recognize that so I can validate the permissions but so far I have been unable to.

Comment: Do you have `app.UseCors` in your startup file at all?

Comment: yes, I created  a policy, and i am using that policy in the controller.

Comment: services.AddCors(opt => opt.AddPolicy("ListarCliente", builder => {
                builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                      .AllowAnyMethod()
                      .AllowAnyHeader()
                      .AllowCredentials();
            }));

Comment: Try doing this in startup.cs as `app.UseCors` right before `app.UseAuthentication()`

Comment: I already have that part in Configure inside de Startup.cs, but I have it this way app.UseCors("policyName");